# How to get suitable model objects out of an array based on given properties?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get suitable model objects out of an array. There are 3 criteria, which should be satisfied by the model objects.

Why gives the "getSuiatblePersons"-function just an empty Person array back? The searching criteria shouldn't have to be comprehensive. A part of the name "Klaus" (for example "laus") together with the other criteria should be enough to get out the first person of "myArray". The order of the search criteria in the `searchCriterias` Array shouldn't matter.

```swift
import UIKit

struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: String
    var place: String
}

let myArray = [
    Person.init(name: "Klaus", age: "90", place: "Boston"),
    Person.init(name: "Peter", age: "10", place: "Hamburg"),
    Person.init(name: "Ute", age: "60", place: "London"),
    Person.init(name: "ralph", age: "49", place: "Washington"),
    Person.init(name: "Inge", age: "100", place: "Boston"),
    Person.init(name: "Karen", age: "30", place: "test"),
]

var searchCriterias = ["laus", "burg", "0"]

func getSuitablePersons(for arrayToFilter: [Person], with searchCriterias: [String]) -> [Person]{
    var result = [Person]()

    result = arrayToFilter.filter({($0.place == searchCriterias[0] || $0.place == searchCriterias[1] || $0.place == searchCriterias[2]) && ($0.name == searchCriterias[0] || $0.name == searchCriterias[1] || $0.name == searchCriterias[2]) && ($0.age == searchCriterias[0] || $0.age == searchCriterias[1] || $0.age == searchCriterias[2])})

    return result
}

getSuitablePersons(for: myArray, with: searchCriterias)
```

Or are there better solutions?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all searching for a `"0"` in terms of a number (an age) is pretty pointless. Lets put that aside.

Your array is empty because you are always comparing the full strings rather than checking if a string **contains** a substring.

A more efficient way is to check for each substring in a loop and return true if one of the checks evaluates to `true`.

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var place: String
}

let myArray = [
    Person.init(name: "Klaus", age: 90, place: "Boston"),
    Person.init(name: "Peter", age: 10, place: "Hamburg"),
    Person.init(name: "Ute", age: 60, place: "London"),
    Person.init(name: "ralph", age: 49, place: "Washington"),
    Person.init(name: "Inge", age: 100, place: "Boston"),
    Person.init(name: "Karen", age: 30, place: "test"),
]

func getSuitablePeople(for arrayToFilter: [Person], with searchCriteria: [String]) -> [Person]{
    return arrayToFilter.filter({ person in
        for criterium in searchCriteria {
            if person.name.range(of: criterium) != nil ||  person.place.range(of: criterium) != nil { return true }
        }
        return false
    })
}

getSuitablePeople(for: myArray, with:  ["laus", "burg"])
// [{name "Klaus", age 90, place "Boston"}, {name "Peter", age 10, place "Hamburg"}]
```

If you want to find all items which fulfill both criteria you have to invert the conditions

```
func getSuitablePeople(for arrayToFilter: [Person], with searchCriteria: [String]) -> [Person]{
    return arrayToFilter.filter({ person in
        for criterium in searchCriteria {
            if person.name.range(of: criterium) == nil && person.place.range(of: criterium) == nil { return false }
        }
        return true
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I expressed myself wrong. So in the example above, there shouldn't be any result, because no person fits all of the two search criterias. Another example: searchCriterias = ["laus", "oston"] => should gives the first item in "myArray" (Klaus, 90, Boston). Have you an idea?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Maybe my questions sounds dump, but I haver never worked with .range(of: ) so far... So is it possible to extend the example from above, in order to work with three criterias? Because let's say, that age actually is an attribute we want to check, too. Something like: "if person.name.range(of: criterium) == nil && person.place.range(of: criterium) == nil && person.age.range(of: criterium) == nil" seems to be not working... (I changed age to an String)